# accidentally i Replace my Synced settings can i restore it?

Tags: json, visual-studio, github, settings

In short, I wanted to transfer visual-studio settings from one computer to another, and at that time I accidentally clicked replace instead of Merge. Can I restore my original settings?

I tried to adjust the settings myself but I can't give it the original look so I need your help